# Policy on posting surveys to the site?

Tags: feature-request, site-scope

Im looking to collect data for a research project. can I post a survey to the main site or meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say no. If allowed, survey questions would probably outnumber other types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

As denesp said, in general no. But if you did want to enquire further, then send an email to team@stackexchange.com and ask the staff.